# Flask Internal Server Error 500

Tags: flask

Internal Server Error  The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: The error message tells you everything we could, so it's unclear what you're asking. Either your server is overloaded (which only your server administrator can address) or you have an error in your application (which we can't do anything about either).

Comment: Very general error that doesn't specify any details. Please consider adding some details

Answer (score 1):

@Alih81, you are a man of extremely few words.  I'm guessing you are using Flask and have a bug in your code.  All you are seeing in the browser is `Internal Server Error ...`.  Flask does this for security reasons (don't want to show hackers anything about your code).

But Flask isn't showing you any useful info elsewhere.  Try setting the environment variable `FLASK_DEBUG=1` before invoking your Flask server.  If using GAE, do `dev_appsever.py app.yaml --env_var FLASK_DEBUG=1`.